# Failed registering Scalable Target when defining auto scale option for ECS

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

[image]

But I am getting this error:

> **Failed registering Scalable Target**
>
> Scalable Target could not register
>   scalable target: 1 validation error detected: Value '' at 'roleARN'
>   failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or
>   equal to 1 (Service: AWSApplicationAutoScaling; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:
>   dff37db1-4be5-11e7-8739-df4df785c602)

[image]

I really don't know how to resolve this issue.

I have used an account `play-admin` to create all these cluster and service. It has the following rights:

[image]

The task is run using this role `play-ecs`:

[image]

I have also put in the trust relationship to this role:[image]

**My Question**:

What permission do I need to grant to get the autoscaling to work? What confuse me greatly is in the message: "Member must have length greater than or
 equal to 1 ", what does this **member** refer to? The IAM account I used to create this autoscaling? The role of the task? Or the newly created 'IAM autoscale role' (see the following screen shot)? If it is the last one, it seems like it is beyond my control.

*This screensot shows that a step `IAM Autoscale role: <create_new>` is executed by ECS

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue today and it appears that when you're setting up the configuration it creates a new IAM role but at the moment of executing the steps you mentioned something happens and that ARN is not passed (this is an AWS bug, I already reported it).

So what I did was try to configure the auto scaling for the service again, but this time it didn't create the `ecsAutoscaleRole` because it was already created, so it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had to add the trust relationship of "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com" on my "ecsAutoscaleRole".